# Haskell: How to filter a list of list?

Tags: haskell

Given a list of list:

```
xss = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
```

I want to filter it by list size then by remainder and then return a list of Int.

Here are my two attempts:

```
concat [[x | x <- xs, mod x 2 == 0] | xs <- xss, length xs > 2]

filter (\x -> mod x 2 == 0) $ concat $ filter (\x -> length x > 2) xss
```

Is there more expressive way to do the same but with less code?

Comment: `[x | xs <- xss, length xs > 2, x <- xs, mod x 2 == 0]`. but chi's answer is better, more *productive* (will work for `[[1..]]`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a built-in `even` function in Haskell, and you can also get help converting to point-free style using [Blunt](https://blunt.herokuapp.com).  This gives you:

```
filter even . concat . filter ((> 2) . length)
```

Comment: `length` is an expensive function to use if you only care that there are at least 3 elements: what if the list has a million items? Better to replace `((> 2) . length)` with something like `(not . null . drop 2)`.

Comment: That's a good point.  However, I prefer to take the hit in readability if and when handling large lists becomes an actual requirement.

Answer (score 3):

A single list comprehension suffices

```
[x | xs@(_:_:_:_) <- xss, x <- xs, mod x 2 == 0]
```

The pattern `(_:_:_:_)` matches all lists having at least three elements.